# Extracting element in R according to a pattern

Tags: r

I have the variable 'qualification' in a df with observations like this:

- a bachelor’s degree and 6 years of experience. At least 3 years of experience in the implementation and management...
- at least 3 years of professional experience with strong recommendations from previous supervisors.    experience in procurement, office administration, logistics management, and event/meeting coordination.
- a ba/s or equivalent in relevant field; ma/s preferred. minimum 5 years’ ngo...
- bachelor's degree required.•  2 years of relevant work experience...

I would like to create the variable exp (year of experience) substracting the number of years form qualification as  for the example above:
exp:
6
3
5
2

How can this be done?

Comment: Please edit the question to show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck. See also: [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`str_extract`](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_extract.html) from `stringr` library:

```
library(stringr)
df <- data.frame(qualification = c("a bachelor's degree and 6 years of experience. At least 3 years of experience in the implementation and management...", "at least 3 years of professional experience with strong recommendations from previous supervisors. experience in procurement, office administration, logistics management, and event/meeting coordination.", "non-matching string"))      
df$exp <- as.numeric(str_extract(df$qualification, "(\\d+)(?=\\s+year)"))
print(df$exp)
## [1]  6  3 NA
```